# Anypoint CLI VS ARM REST Services (which one is preferred for Automated Deployment?) Using Cloud Console on-premis Deployment

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft, cloudhub

I wanted to Automate the Cloud Console on-premis Deployment process. I see two options to deploy the services using anypoint-cli or Rest API. Can some one please let me know what are the differences between them and which one should i choose(In terms of long term support) ?

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint cli is a command line tool to interact with the REST API. It might not provide access to every endpoint of the API.
Using the API directly requires that you make the API requests in some programming or scripting language.
You should choose the one that makes more sense to you, and your use case.  That can not be determined here.